# Save As PDF reduces image quality even when "Do not compress images" is enabled

Tags: pdf, png, save-as

I'm using Microsoft Word and have the settings set to *High Fidelity* and *Do not compress images in File* but when I do *Save as PDF* with PNG images in them, they still get compressed and lose quality. I used [this link suggestion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-resolution-for-inserting-pictures-in-office-f4aca5b4-6332-48c6-9488-bf5e0094a7d2).

[image]

If I check *PDF/A compliant* it does help improve quality but still not PNG quality.

[image]

It still compressed the image to JPG instead of retaining PNG quality despite the *Do not compress images* option enabled. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that [as of 2020 Microsoft still has not fixed this issue](https://superuser.com/a/1563263/1553868).  Instead of using "Save As", if you are using Windows 10 or above, Windows comes with a PDF printer called "Microsoft Print to PDF" (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1296204/1553868)), or you can also use a third party PDF printer (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/743049/1553868) that allows you to set the DPI).

For more information, see this highly voted [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/645657/1553868) for other solutions such as converting the PNG to an EMF first (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1365506/1553868)).

Comment: hey thanks alot for your answer! i will check it out tomorrow!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie No problem.  I'll suggest something else if it doesn't work.  Otherwise, you can "accept" the answer.  Good luck!